# Heroku CLI unhandled error event at events.js:291 when deploying Java Web Application

Tags: java, netbeans, ant, heroku-cli

I'm trying to deploy my Java Ant web application (built in NetBeans IDE) to Heroku and I keep getting this error code: [Error Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/blIbU.png)

I've deployed an application previously to Heroku and I had no problem with it back then. But I cannot get it to work now. Can someone please help?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Heroku, but just as a note: code (including error messages) should be inserted as text and formatted accordingly. If you make the effort, your post will be more searchable - unlike a screenshot.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please avoid uploading code as an image. 
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question  . Good luck 